# Installing pc-dawson-xenial-amd64-m4-20180507-32.iso on 7iNUC installs Snappy, not Desktop as promised

Tags: 16.04

Following the link in : https://ubuntu.com/download/iot/intel-nuc-desktop

I downloaded pc-dawson-xenial-amd64-m4-20180507-32.iso and installed via bootable USB stick.

Rather than a 16.04 LTS Desktop release, I have an install of a Core 'snappy' version.

If this is just the first boot stage, then I'm confused.   enet is working, ssh in works, so the core version is functional.

What am I doing wrong?